# Ajax not firing the done callback when form is posted for the first time, however second post works

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I have a form which I am posting using the JS below. When I start a debug session in Visual Studio, the first form submission does not trigger the done callback and I am redirected to the form. On the second submission the done callback is triggered and my redirection works. I can confirm that the OnDone function is called on both occasions and no errors have occurred. The form is posted to a Razor page which is responding with a new OkResult(). Does anyone know why the done called does not work the during the first post?

```js
function onDone(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $("#wizard");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "@Url.Page("Index","Submit")",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", 
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: form.serialize(),
    // dataType: 'json',
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
  }).success(function(data) {
    console.log("Done hit")
    window.location.href = '/FormComplete';
    //  kendo.alert(data.success);
    //  form.getKendoForm().clear();
  });
}
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The [`jqXHR` object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) no longer has a `.success()` method as of version 3. You should be using `.done()` instead

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Try clearing your browser cache

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.12.4. I have cleared the cache, but the result is the same.

Comment: Wow, that version is ancient. At least move up to version 2.

Comment: I'm using some Telerik components and the VS template they provided was using that version. I was surprised how old it was too. I have just started using v2, but I'm unfortunately encountering the same issue.